# Relating real integrability and integration over the unit disk.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose we have a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$, such that $\int_0^1f < \infty$.

Is it always true that $\int_\mathbb{D} f(|z|)dA < \infty$ ?   $dA$ is area measure.

If so, how does one prove such a statement?

I know that if $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is differentiable, with $\int_0^1t^2f' < \infty$, we could use the fundamental theorem of calculus, and tonelli's theorem to get the result.

That is,

$ \int_\mathbb{D} f(|z|)dA = \int_D \int_0^{|z|} f'(t)dtDA=\int_0^1 \int_{\{z: |z|\le t\}}f'(t)dAdt=\pi\int_0^1t^2f'(t)dt < \infty$

But this isn't all that interesting because it misses all the functions we would care about, like $f(t)=t^a$, for $-1<a<0$.

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, or I have an error in my understanding of something basic, but it seems reasonable that it should be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: we have
$$ \int_D f(\lvert z \rvert ) \, dA = \int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} f(r) r \, d\theta \, dr $$
by Fubini's theorem. Then
$$ 0 \leqslant \int_D f(\lvert z \rvert ) \, dA = 2\pi \int_0^1 r f(r) \, dr \leqslant 2\pi \int_0^1 f < \infty $$

Answer (score 0):

Integrate in polar coordinates and you get $$\int_{\Bbb D}f(|z|)\,dA=2\pi\int_0^1r\,f(r)\,dr\le 2\pi\int_0^1 f.$$